# jupyter notebook - import modules - NOT a SYS.PATH issue - the paths didn't change since I last ran notebook

Tags: docker, module, jupyter-notebook

I am running jupiter notebook from a docker container, everything was working just fine yesterday as far as all the models I was importing, until my laptop's battery died and when I charged and retstarted it, NONE of my imports were working, got error of

"No module named 'insertmodulenamehere'"

for ALL models, plotly, datetime, NOTHING. What could have possibly changed?? I looked up other people who had this issue but it seemed like it can't possibly be the sys.path issue